# Using Javascript to identify and input text to input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to be able to identify all input fields so that i can store them and run  a for loop which will input text into the input fields from an array and submit the form for a response.

```
var inputs = document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("input");
var text = ["brown", "white", "blue", "green"]


for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    for (word of text){
        document.getElementById(inputs[i]).textContent(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: `text.forEach((word, i) => { ... });` (you have nested loops, but you want to iterate over both iterables at the same time)

Comment: You might want to change this `document.getElementById(inputs[i]).textContent(word)` to `document.getElementById(inputs[i]).textContent = word`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `getElementsByTagName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) or `document.forms`. Those are old APIs that have drawbacks.

Instead, use `.querySelectorAll()` and take advantage of the fact that you can loop over the results of `.querySelectorAll()` with the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method like this:

```js
var values = ["brown", "white", "blue", "green"];

// Loop over all the inputs
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(input, index){
   // Set the current input with the corresponding item from the values array
   input.value = values[index];
});


// Submit the form
document.querySelector("form").submit();
```

```html
<form action="https://www.example.com" method="post">
  <div>Input 1 <input name="item1"></div>
  <div>Input 2 <input name="item2"></div>
  <div>Input 3 <input name="item3"></div>
  <div>Input 4 <input name="item4"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop text and no need `document.getElementById` because already get element
for change values use value not textContent

```js
var inputs = document.forms["myForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
var text = ["brown", "white", "blue", "green"]

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     inputs[i].value  = text[i];
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" >
f Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
m Name: <input type="text" name="mname">
l Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
dob: <input type="text" name="dob">

</form>
<button>Go to Next</button>
```